# Css text overflow ellipsis not working

Tags: html, css

This is my code:

```
<ul class="results">
   <li class="item"> <span class="title"><a href="item.html" target="_blank">The numbers in the table specify the first browser version that fully supports the property</a></span><span class="place">Place</span>
   </li>
   <li class="item"> <span class="title"><a href="item.html" target="_blank">The numbers in the table specify the first browser version that fully supports the property</a></span><span class="place">Place</span>
   </li>
</ul>
```

I am using the css:

```
.results  {text-overflow: ellipsis;}
```

However it doesn't seem to work on the content I have, and just overflows as normal. Can anyone tell me where I am going wrong please?

http://jsfiddle.net/m6krvapf/3/

Comment: Apply it to the .item and disallow line breaks: http://jsfiddle.net/m6krvapf/4/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must apply `text-overflow:ellipsis` to `.item` , plus `text-overflow:ellipsis` can't be applied alone.

> This property only affects content that is overflowing a block
>   container element in its inline progression direction (not text
>   overflowing at the bottom of a box, for example). Text can overflow
>   when it is prevented from wrapping (e.g., due to ‘`white-space:nowrap`’)
>   or a single word being too long to fit.
>
> This CSS property doesn't force an overflow to occur; to do so and
>   make text-overflow to be applied, the author must apply some
>   additional properties on the element, like setting `overflow` to `hidden`.

[**More info**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-overflow)

#### so here is a snippet below

```css
.item {
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap
}
```

```html
<ul class="results">
  <li class="item">
    <span class="title">
      <a href="item.html" target="_blank">The numbers in the table specify the first browser version that fully supports the property The numbers in the table specify the first browser version that fully supports the property The numbers in the table specify the first browser version that fully supports the property The numbers in the table specify the first browser version that fully supports the property The numbers in the table specify the first browser version that fully supports the property </a>
    </span>
    <span class="place">Place</span>
  </li>
  <li class="item">
    <span class="title">
      <a href="item.html" target="_blank">The numbers in the table specify the first browser version that fully supports the property The numbers in the table specify the first browser version that fully supports the property The numbers in the table specify the first browser version that fully supports the property The numbers in the table specify the first browser version that fully supports the property The numbers in the table specify the first browser version that fully supports the property The numbers in the table specify the first browser version that fully supports the property The numbers in the table specify the first browser version that fully supports the property The numbers in the table specify the first browser version that fully supports the property</a>
    </span>
    <span class="place">Place</span>
  </li>
</ul>
```

#### If needed you may add `width` to your `.item` like this below

```css
.item {
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  width: 150px
}
```

```html
<ul class="results">
  <li class="item">
    <span class="title">
      <a href="item.html" target="_blank">The numbers in the table specify the first browser version that fully supports the property The numbers in the table specify the first browser version that fully supports the property The numbers in the table specify the first browser version that fully supports the property The numbers in the table specify the first browser version that fully supports the property The numbers in the table specify the first browser version that fully supports the property </a>
    </span>
    <span class="place">Place</span>
  </li>
  <li class="item">
    <span class="title">
      <a href="item.html" target="_blank">The numbers in the table specify the first browser version that fully supports the property The numbers in the table specify the first browser version that fully supports the property The numbers in the table specify the first browser version that fully supports the property The numbers in the table specify the first browser version that fully supports the property The numbers in the table specify the first browser version that fully supports the property The numbers in the table specify the first browser version that fully supports the property The numbers in the table specify the first browser version that fully supports the property The numbers in the table specify the first browser version that fully supports the property</a>
    </span>
    <span class="place">Place</span>
  </li>
</ul>
```

#### I'm guessing you want your class `.place` to always show therefore you need to add `display:inline-block`to `.title` ( because `span` has a initial value of `inline`)

```css
.title {
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 150px
}
```

```html
<ul class="results">
  <li class="item">
    <span class="title">
      <a href="item.html" target="_blank">The numbers in the table specify the first browser version that fully supports the property The numbers in the table specify the first browser version that fully supports the property The numbers in the table specify the first browser version that fully supports the property The numbers in the table specify the first browser version that fully supports the property The numbers in the table specify the first browser version that fully supports the property </a>
    </span>
    <span class="place">Place</span>
  </li>
  <li class="item">
    <span class="title">
      <a href="item.html" target="_blank">The numbers in the table specify the first browser version that fully supports the property The numbers in the table specify the first browser version that fully supports the property The numbers in the table specify the first browser version that fully supports the property The numbers in the table specify the first browser version that fully supports the property The numbers in the table specify the first browser version that fully supports the property The numbers in the table specify the first browser version that fully supports the property The numbers in the table specify the first browser version that fully supports the property The numbers in the table specify the first browser version that fully supports the property</a>
    </span>
    <span class="place">Place</span>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the code.

```css
.results .item  {
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<ul class="results">
   <li class="item"> <span class="title"><a href="item.html" target="_blank">The numbers in the table specify the first browser version that fully supports the property</a></span><span class="place">Place</span>
   </li>
   <li class="item"> <span class="title"><a href="item.html" target="_blank">The numbers in the table specify the first browser version that fully supports the property</a></span><span class="place">Place</span>
   </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Also here is a article on it that may help: http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/truncate-string-with-ellipsis/