# CSS overflow ellipsis only on first element

Tags: html, css

I am trying to do it so for each line the "place" is always shown. However I want the title to be the one which has the ellipsis when the content is too long.

This is what I have so far:

```
<ul class="results">
   <li class="item"> <span class="title"><a href="item.html" target="_blank">The numbers in the table specify the first browser version that fully supports the property</a></span><span class="place">Place</span>
   </li>
</ul>

.item {
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/m6krvapf/5/

The trouble is it is the end of the line which is cut off, which means the "place" is cut off first. Is it possible to kepe the place there always and only put the ellipsis on the content to the left of it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Css text overflow ellipsis not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28154305/css-text-overflow-ellipsis-not-working)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can just wrap the part you want to be ellipsised like so:

```
<li class="item"> 
    <span class="ellipsis"><span class="title"><a href="item.html" target="_blank">The numbers in the table specify the first browser version that fully supports the property</a></span></span>
    <span class="place">Place</span>
</li>
```

then use the following styles:

```
.item {
    white-space: nowrap;
}
.ellipsis {
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    overflow: hidden;
    display:inline-block;
    max-width:85%;
}
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/m6krvapf/12/)

For smaller screens where *Place* is longer than 15% of the screen (around 230px), you can use the following media query:

```
@media all and (max-width: 230px) {
    .item {
        overflow:auto;
        padding-right: 3em;
    }

    .ellipsis {
        max-width:none;
        width:100%;
        float:left;
    }

    .place 
    {
        display:inline-block;
        width:3em;
        float:right; 
        margin-right:-3em;
    }
}
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/m6krvapf/17/)

Comment: Hi Pete. This seems to work perfectly except when I make the window smaller it gives me a horizontal scroll bar instead of removing content from the text. That is to say, there should never be a horizontal scroll bar. Have I explained that ok? :s

Comment: You may need to add a media query in for the extremely small screens to change the max width - I'll try something and post a comment

Answer (score 2):

You can turn spans to blocks, use css floating and swap their place as in [this Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/m6krvapf/6/), css follows:

```
.item span {
    display: block;
}
.title {
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap
}
.place {
    float: right;
}
```

for this html:

```
<ul class="results">
    <li class="item">
        <span class="place">Place</span>
        <span class="title"><a href="item.html" target="_blank">The numbers in the table specify the first browser version that fully supports the property</a></span>
    </li>
    <li class="item">
        <span class="place">Place</span>
        <span class="title"><a href="item.html" target="_blank">The numbers in the table specify the first browser version that fully supports the property</a></span>
    </li>
</ul>
```

That way 'Place' stays on right side always. Other solution would be to use original html, but to make spans blocks, float them left and set `max-width` for `span.title` as in [this Example](http://jsfiddle.net/m6krvapf/16/), which uses this CSS:

```
.item span {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    line-height: 1em;
}
.title {
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
    max-width: calc(100% - 50px);
}
```

Comment: Very good. So float will give span a "space" or say "width" and Only then we will be able to apply text overflow property, is that the right explanation?

Comment: This is a good solution, except that it right aligns the "place" when really I want it left aligned but to the right of the text. Is that possible?

Comment: No, span must be a block or inline-block for ellipsis, can't apply on inline elements. `This property only affects content that is overflowing a block container element in its inline progression direction` [more...](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-overflow)

Answer (score 0):

Or you can use a JS function to  crop you text and then replace the ... for whatever you want.

```
function shorten(text, maxLength) {
var ret = text;
if (ret.length > maxLength) {
    ret = ret.substr(0,maxLength-3) + "...";
}
return ret;
```

}

See here:
http://html5hub.com/ellipse-my-text/